# Selenium | How to click while an item is not loaded

Tags: python, selenium

how to click on an element until another is not loaded
I searched used this

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, )))
```

but I can't find a way to adapt the wait until to click until
so do you have a solution?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, do you want to click on some element until a different element is loaded?

Comment: What is your exact usecase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem. However, I suggest you research if this might work for you:

```
loading = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("your-loading-item")
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(loading))
```